# Uploading specific files with specific values into one mastersheet and add it to a different column depending on the date

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple sheets that I want to donwload on a frequent basis. The issue is that the sheet is in a specific folder and via a button I want to select the files and upload the specific values in the table to the mastersheet. The values of the different sheets needs to be placed in a different column / row that is specified according to the date and the row (Header).

For Example

```
Descr.    Jan15   Feb15   Mar15   Apr15           
A         50      100          
B         70      20
C         60      50
```

Can somebody help me in fixing the problem?

Enclosed the code I used so far:

Sub Enterknop()
    Dim Report As Sheet1
    Dim Bron As Sheet1
    Set Report = Sheets("Report")

```
'**************************************
'Process Report 1 
'**************************************
R1 = Report.Cells(37, 4)
Workbooks.Open Filename:=R1
Set Bron = Active.Sheets(1)

Range("A1:AO28").Select
Selection.Cut
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Main Sheet_Business.xls").Activate
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("TOP25.xls").Activate
ActiveWindow.Close
```

End Sub

Comment: Please be a bit more specific on what your task is and show us some code or what you have tried so far.

Comment: That is the code I already created but I cannot find a way how I can create a code that the results are placed e.g. March 15 and the next time in Apr15 based on a list box that is filled with Dates.

Comment: Sub Enterknop()
    Dim Report As Worksheet
    Dim Bron As Worksheet
    Set Report = Sheets("Report")
    
         
'Process Report 1
    R4 = Report.Cells(4, 20)
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=R4
    Set Bron = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1) ActiveWorkbook.Close End Sub

'Numbers of items in Report files
'Row containing header names
Const rhead = 1
'Column for monthly results
Const cmaand = 5
'Category code
Const ccatcod = 1
'Category description
Const ccatdes = 2
'Nr. of ult par
Const cnrultpar = 3

Comment: Please edit that into your question.